# Floating Point Exception from my for loop that is not initialized correctly

Tags: c, floating-point

I keep getting a floating point expection on my program that is trying to determine if a number is prime or not in C. I used this loop:

```
for(i=1:i<num/2:i++) 
  (if num%i==0)
```

then it is prime. Please help!

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: Probably you aren't initializing num, but can't know without the entire function

Comment: What language is this?  Certainly not C.

Comment: @AlexaBurger the for which you try look's like this **for( ; ; )**, now, what you decide to do with it, well that's your problem. remember a for has **; and ;** and not **; and :**

Comment: There are several formatting errors in that snippet.  It shouldn’t even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping at the square root of the *num* variable is sufficient , here's a sample code doing the job you're asking for in a correct form :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void main()
{
 int i,num;
 printf("Enter a number to check if it is prime or not : ");
 scanf("%d",&num);

 for(i=2 ; i <= (int)sqrt(num) ; i++)
  if(num%i==0) 
  {
    printf("%d is not prime ",num);
    break;
  }
 if(i > (int)sqrt(num))
   printf("%d is prime");
}
```